# MultiValueDictKeyError on django

Tags: python, django

home.html

```
 {% extends 'base.html'%}
 {%block content%}
 <h1>hello word{{name}}</h1>

 <form action="add">
 <label>fname</label><input type="text" name="fn">
 <label>lname</label><input type="text"name="ln">
 <input type="submit" >
 </form>
 {%endblock%}
```

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="red">

{%block content%}

{%endblock%}

<p>hello dhiraj how are you</p>
</body>
```

result.html

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{%block content%}

Result is :{{result}}
{%endblock%}
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [

  path('',views.index ,name="index"),
  path('add',views.add,name="add")
 ]
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'home.html',{'name':'dhiraj'})
   

def add(request):
    val1=request.GET["fn"]
    val2=request.GET["ln"]
    res=val1+val2
    return render(request,'result.html',{'result':res})
```

getting error is

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /add
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\ero\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 76, in 
 __getitem__
 list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'fn'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\ero\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, 
 in inner
 response = get_response(request)
 File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\ero\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in 
 _get_response
 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\fproject\fapp\views.py", line 11, in add
 val1=request.GET["fn"]
 File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\ero\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, 
in __getitem__
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'fn'
[09/May/2021 17:14:11] "GET /add? HTTP/1.1" 500 73579
Internal Server Error: /add
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\ero\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 76, in 
__getitem__
list_ = super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'fn'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\ero\lib\site-   
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
 response = get_response(request)
 File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\ero\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in 
 _get_response
 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\fproject\fapp\views.py", line 11, in add
val1=request.GET["fn"]
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\fpro\ero\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 78, 
 in __getitem__
raise MultiValueDictKeyError(key)

 django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'fn'
[09/May/2021 17:14:12] "GET /add? HTTP/1.1" 500 73579
```

Due to the above mentioned error, my form is not getting displayed. Please help me in identifying and resolving the issue. i am relly trouble on this issue please help me I am really trouble on this issue thank you form are not display on screen why this problem occurs please help me

Comment: Also in template use `url`  [template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url):`<form action="{% url 'add' %}">`

Answer (score 2):

It means that you don't have the key **`fn`** in your **GET**.

You should use method [**`get()`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/205c36b58fed5a1a0ff462593fc61b58189027d8/django/utils/datastructures.py#L117) of [`MultiValueDict`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/205c36b58fed5a1a0ff462593fc61b58189027d8/django/utils/datastructures.py#L49):

```
def add(request):
    val1=request.GET.get("fn", "")
    val2=request.GET.get("ln", "")
    res=val1+val2
    return render(request,'result.html',{'result':res})
```